# Reading a file in C++ in one block, can't output the contents

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, memory-management, dynamic

I wrote a very simple program to read the contents of a text file in one block and save it into a buffer then display the contents of that buffer with the size of the buffer, although i compiled the exact code in Windows 7 it was just working fine however whenever i compile it on my mac there is no buffer output at all with the size of buffer returning -1, iam not getting any error during compilation

myfile.txt content

**hello world !!!**

**A B C D E F G H I ... Z**

**a b c d e f g h i ... z**

my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    fstream myfile;
    myfile.open("myText.txt");

    myfile.seekg(0,ios::end);
    long int size =  myfile.tellg();
    myfile.clear();
    myfile.seekg(0,ios::beg);

    char* buffer = new (nothrow) char[size];

    myfile.read(buffer,size);

    myfile.close();

     for (int i = 1; i < size;i++ )
         if ((buffer[i]>= 65 && buffer[i] <=90) || (buffer[i] >= 97 && buffer[i] <= 122) ||       buffer[i] == ' ' || buffer[i]== '\n')
              cout << buffer[i];
    cout << size;

    delete [] buffer;

    getchar();

    return 0;
```

I checked the file reading operation via:

```
if(myfile.good() == false)
    cout << "Error openning the file \n";
if(myfile.bad() == true)
    cout << "Read/writing error on i/o operation \n";
if (myfile.fail() == true)
    cout <<"Logical error on i/o operation \n";
```

my output :

**Error openning the file**

**Logical error on i/o operation**

**-1**

Comment: Why loop start from 1?

Comment: @Ran when i used 0 as the starting point for the loop, it usually typed an extra junk character before the actual text, so i ended up using 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are not opening the file: probably it worked in Windows because the filename is not case sensitive, while on Mac it is. (And anyway, you are saying your file is called myfile.txt and in your program you are opening myText.txt)

Check your file has been correctly opened.

Comment: i've checked it, it is returning an error, previously when i compiled in windows i specified the path to the file, but with mac i placed the file in my project folder and included the file in my project, so do i still need to specify the path?

Comment: of course you do. The fstream doesn't know about your xcode project. You can specify a relative path (as in "./MyFile" or "MyFile", which is equivalent) which means "the file named "MyFile" in this directory (this directory being the one where the executable is located) or an absolute path (something like "/Users/.../MyFile")

Answer (score 1):

you should test if myfile.good() right after myfile.open(...)

Comment: i've edited my question for further information regarding checking my file reading operations..

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that it's not opening the file correctly because it is looking at the wrong path. I had this same issue when working on a project last month.

The file is at the right place, but Xcode is looking at the wrong directory. You need to specify the directory by changing the scheme. Go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme, and on options you can choose your working directory, which you should change to your project folder. Then it should read the file correctly.